# `pip3 install psutil` Error - Repository Not Found

Tags: python, pip, installation

I am running the command `pip3 install psutil`, but running into the following error:

```html
me$ pip3 install psutil
Collecting psutil
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/51/9e/0f8f5423ce28c9109807024f7bdde776ed0b1161de20b408875de7e030c3/psutil-5.4.6.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    running egg_info
    creating pip-egg-info/psutil.egg-info
    writing pip-egg-info/psutil.egg-info/PKG-INFO
    writing dependency_links to pip-egg-info/psutil.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
    writing top-level names to pip-egg-info/psutil.egg-info/top_level.txt
    writing manifest file 'pip-egg-info/psutil.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
    error: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '': ''
    abort: no repository found in '/private/var/folders/n2/2rxj0k0d3bb73gbfstgcgzs40000gp/T/pip-install-y27z_s2w/psutil' (.hg not found)!

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/n2/2rxj0k0d3bb73gbfstgcgzs40000gp/T/pip-install-y27z_s2w/psutil/
```

I've tried everything and cannot find a solution - it works fine using `pip install psutil`.
This isn't the only package that this error is occurring on.

Any help would be appreciated!
Thanks!

Comment: Did you try sudo 'apt-get install python-psutil'? (if you are using ubuntu)

Comment: Fire `sudo apt-get install mercurial` and then `pip3 install psutil`

Comment: Using a mac - I just uninstalled both 2.7 and 3, and uninstalled mercurial then `brew install`-ed both python@2 and python@3, working fine now :) Thank you!

Comment: Great! Enjoy solution :)

Answer (score 0):

Uninstalled both 2.7 and 3, and uninstalled mercurial then brew install-ed both python@2 and python@3.